# How to remove duplicated form element in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 input fields that should be displayed adjacent to each other on devices except mobile. On mobile, it is to be displayed in rows one after another (each wrapped with row class).  My current code is below and form is duplicated.  Is there a way to remove duplication?

```
<form... class="hidden-xs">
  <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" name="field1">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" name="field2">
     </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form... class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" name="field1">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" name="field2">
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it to below code, it does the same task as in this [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/a3dm1szg/)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" name="field1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" name="field2">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But I need a row between two inputs to main uniform spacing between fields on col-xs*.

Comment: Even with multiple rows, there is no space. You can use a `<br>` tag between the input fields or use `margin-top` on the second input.